# 8 tile solver with repeated nodes - Python

Tags: python, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search, heuristics, solver

i'm trying to solve the 8tile puzzle using techniques like BFS search, DFS, Greedy and A* using Manhattan distance as my heuristic solution.

The problem is that while i can solve some good number of problems, the problem is with some of the puzzles, it can occur that the children i get on expanding the parent node can already be in the older nodes.

I don't know if i was able to explain myself well, but my main problem is everything i tried to see if the new nodes that i create aren't already on the old nodes.

With this problem i usually get to depth 9 and then my program doesn't advance or give solution.

One of my ideias was using the code:

```
if node in prev:
    continue
prev.append(node)
```

But i guess i'm going the wrong way.

I'm doing this on python and here's my code in case someone can help me.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import copy


class Board:
    def __init__(self, matrix, whitepos=None):
        self.matrix = matrix
        self.whitepos = whitepos
        if not whitepos:
            for y in xrange(3):
                for x in xrange(3):
                    if board[y][x] == 0:
                        self.whitepos = (x, y)


def is_final_state(board):
    final = [[1, 2, 3], [8, 0, 4], [7, 6, 5]]
    for y in xrange(3):
        for x in xrange(3):
            if board.matrix[y][x] != final[y][x]:
                return False
    return True


def get_whitepos(board):
    return board.whitepos


def move(board, x, y, dx, dy):
    b = copy.deepcopy(board.matrix)
    b[y][x] = b[y + dy][x + dx]
    b[y + dy][x + dx] = 0
    return Board(b, (x + dx, y + dy))


def manhattan_heur(board):
    finalpos = [(1, 1), (0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (1, 2), (0, 2),
                (0, 1)]
    cost = 0
    for y in xrange(3):
        for x in xrange(3):
            t = board.matrix[y][x]
            xf, yf = finalpos[t]
            cost += abs(xf - x) + abs(yf - y)
    return cost


def wrongplace_heur(board):
    finalpos = [(1, 1), (0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (1, 2), (0, 2),
                (0, 1)]
    cost = 0
    for y in xrange(3):
        for x in xrange(3):
            t = board.matrix[y][x]
            if finalpos[t] != (x, y):
                cost += 1
    return cost


def heuristic(board):
    return manhattan_heur(board)


class Node:
    def __init__(self, board, parent):
        self.state = board
        self.parent = parent
        if not parent:
            self.g = 0
        else:
            self.g = parent.g + 1
        self.h = heuristic(board)

    def test_goal(self):
        return is_final_state(self.state)

    def expand(self):
        children = []
        b = self.state
        x, y = get_whitepos(b)
        if x > 0:
            children.append(Node(move(b, x, y, -1, 0), self))
        if x < 2:
            children.append(Node(move(b, x, y, +1, 0), self))
        if y > 0:
            children.append(Node(move(b, x, y, 0, -1), self))
        if y < 2:
            children.append(Node(move(b, x, y, 0, +1), self))
        return children


class Solution:
    def __init__(self, node, mem_needed, steps):
        self.node = node
        self.mem_needed = mem_needed
        self.iterations = steps

    def inc(self, other):
        self.node = other.node
        self.mem_needed = max(self.mem_needed, other.mem_needed)
        self.iterations += other.iterations


def search(board, queue_fn, queue_arg=None):
    max_nodes = 1
    steps = 0
    nodes = [Node(Board(board), None)]
    prev = []
    depth = 0
    while nodes:
        node = nodes.pop(0)

        if node.g > depth:
            depth = node.g
            print depth

        if node in prev:
            continue
        prev.append(node)

        if node.test_goal():
            return Solution(node, max_nodes, steps)
        new_nodes = node.expand()
        nodes = queue_fn(nodes, new_nodes, queue_arg)

        max_nodes = max(max_nodes, len(nodes))
        steps += 1
    return Solution(None, max_nodes, steps)


def fifo_queue(nodes, new_nodes, _):
    nodes.extend(new_nodes)
    return nodes


def bl_search(board):
    return search(board, fifo_queue)


def lifo_queue(nodes, new_nodes, _):
    new_nodes.extend(nodes)
    return new_nodes


def dfs_search(board):
    return search(board, lifo_queue)


def bpl_queue(nodes, new_nodes, max_depth):
    def f(n):
        return n.g <= max_depth

    new_nodes = filter(f, new_nodes)
    new_nodes.extend(nodes)
    return new_nodes


def bpi_search(board):
    solution = Solution(None, 0, 0)
    for max_depth in xrange(0, sys.maxint):
        sol = search(board, bpl_queue, max_depth)
        solution.inc(sol)
        if solution.node:
            return solution


def sort_queue(nodes, new_nodes, cmp):
    nodes.extend(new_nodes)
    nodes.sort(cmp)
    return nodes


def guloso2_search(board):
    def cmp(n1, n2):
        return n1.h - n2.h

    return search(board, sort_queue, cmp)


def astar_search(board):
    def cmp(n1, n2):
        return (n1.g + n1.h) - (n2.g + n2.h)

    return search(board, sort_queue, cmp)


def print_solution(search, sol):
    print
    print "*", search
    node = sol.node
    if node:
        print "moves:", node.g
        while node:
            print "\t", node.state.matrix
            node = node.parent
    else:
        print "no solution found"
    print "nodes needed:", sol.mem_needed
    print "iterations:  ", sol.iterations


board = [[6, 5, 7], [2, 0, 1], [8, 4, 3]]

print_solution("bl", bl_search(board))
print_solution("dfs", dfs_search(board))
print_solution("bpi", bpi_search(board))
print_solution("guloso2", guloso2_search(board))
print_solution("astar", astar_search(board))
```

Comment: Eight spaces is somewhat irregular for Python programming. People might find it easier to read (and more likely to answer) if you switched to four spaces.

Comment: i was having problem posting the code since it was my first time posting code in here and that's why it came with 8 spaces

Comment: Reformatted it for you and replaced some weird `if x == None:` and `if x != None:` with `if not x:` and `if x:`.

Comment: thanks. i must practice the code formatting a little more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're going about it the right way, but you need to define the `__eq__` and `__ne__` methods in the Node class; otherwise `node in prev` will always return `False` because Python doesn't know how to compare `node` to the items in the list. Check out the [Python data model documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) for more on how comparisons work on user-defined types.

I grabbed your code and added a couple of (very naive) methods to do the equality checking, and it no longer appears to be hanging. It's also worth noting that your classes ought to be inheriting from the base `object` (see below). These are the changes I made (in context):

```
class Board(object):
    def __init__(self, matrix, whitepos=None):
        self.matrix = matrix
        self.whitepos = whitepos
        if not whitepos:
            for y in xrange(3):
                for x in xrange(3):
                    if board[y][x] == 0:
                        self.whitepos = (x, y)
    def __eq__(self, o):
        # Note that comparing whitepos is not strictly necessary; but I left 
        # it in as a safety measure in case the board state gets corrupted.
        # If speed becomes an issue, take it out.
        return (self.matrix, self.whitepos) == (o.matrix, o.whitepos)

class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, board, parent):
        self.state = board
        self.parent = parent
        if not parent:
            self.g = 0
        else:
            self.g = parent.g + 1
        self.h = heuristic(board)

    def test_goal(self):
        return is_final_state(self.state)

    def expand(self):
        children = []
        b = self.state
        x, y = get_whitepos(b)
        if x > 0:
            children.append(Node(move(b, x, y, -1, 0), self))
        if x < 2:
            children.append(Node(move(b, x, y, +1, 0), self))
        if y > 0:
            children.append(Node(move(b, x, y, 0, -1), self))
        if y < 2:
            children.append(Node(move(b, x, y, 0, +1), self))
        return children

    def __eq__(self, o):
        # Note that you don't have to compare parents, since your goal
        # is to eliminate ANY nodes with the same position.
        return self.state == o.state

class Solution(object):
    def __init__(self, node, mem_needed, steps):
        self.node = node
        self.mem_needed = mem_needed
        self.iterations = steps

    def inc(self, other):
        self.node = other.node
        self.mem_needed = max(self.mem_needed, other.mem_needed)
        self.iterations += other.iterations

#...

print_solution("bl", bl_search(board))
# I commented out all but the first search to avoid cluttering up the output.
```

With these changes, the code does produce a solution (I'll leave it up to you to verify that it's correct, but here's my output).

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20

* bl
moves: 20
    [[1, 2, 3], [8, 0, 4], [7, 6, 5]]
    [[1, 2, 3], [8, 6, 4], [7, 0, 5]]
    [[1, 2, 3], [8, 6, 4], [0, 7, 5]]
    [[1, 2, 3], [0, 6, 4], [8, 7, 5]]
    [[1, 2, 3], [6, 0, 4], [8, 7, 5]]
    [[1, 0, 3], [6, 2, 4], [8, 7, 5]]
    [[0, 1, 3], [6, 2, 4], [8, 7, 5]]
    [[6, 1, 3], [0, 2, 4], [8, 7, 5]]
    [[6, 1, 3], [2, 0, 4], [8, 7, 5]]
    [[6, 1, 3], [2, 7, 4], [8, 0, 5]]
    [[6, 1, 3], [2, 7, 4], [8, 5, 0]]
    [[6, 1, 3], [2, 7, 0], [8, 5, 4]]
    [[6, 1, 0], [2, 7, 3], [8, 5, 4]]
    [[6, 0, 1], [2, 7, 3], [8, 5, 4]]
    [[6, 7, 1], [2, 0, 3], [8, 5, 4]]
    [[6, 7, 1], [2, 5, 3], [8, 0, 4]]
    [[6, 7, 1], [2, 5, 3], [8, 4, 0]]
    [[6, 7, 1], [2, 5, 0], [8, 4, 3]]
    [[6, 7, 0], [2, 5, 1], [8, 4, 3]]
    [[6, 0, 7], [2, 5, 1], [8, 4, 3]]
    [[6, 5, 7], [2, 0, 1], [8, 4, 3]]
nodes needed: 44282
iterations:   59930
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i was trying to do some methods to compare but i started to get confused using lines like
parentNode = Node(node.state, node.parent)
and similar ones and my program started to give a lot of errors. xD

Before i got frustrated even more i thought on asking help to see if there's an easy method to make the repetitive nodes get away

Comment: Really? [I tried this](http://ideone.com/rPnxct) and it seems it works without comparison operators.

Comment: I copied his code and added naive `__eq__` methods to Board and Node, and it seems to be working (the depth keeps advancing, at any rate; haven't gotten a solution yet).

Comment: an friend of mine is doing this on java and his solver gets to depth 20 and returns the solution.

dfs on other hand i guess it's normal that it wont give a solution anytime soon but bfs should work in less than 60 secs.

Comment: @WaleedKhan that works because it's literally the same object: when no `__cmp__`, `__eq__`, or `__ne__` are defined, Python compares them by object identity. That works for dummy classes, but not for the OP's case.

Comment: @RasecNoir I added some basic comparison operators to my answer (the ones I used) to help you out on that front. It's probably also worth mentioning that I haven't seen a solution yet, but it's gone through 22ish levels and jumped back up to 0 several times, so there's probably something going wrong elsewhere as well.

Comment: i guess so. if it goes more than 20 it really means something is wrong.

Guess it's more complicated than i thought. 

Thanks for the answer and i'll keep working on this and let's see if someone else can make my code work. 

I guess if i solve this problem all my search options besides BFS will work fine.

Comment: @RasecNoir I did a run just using the first search (which I'm assuming is BFS, but your naming could be a bit clearer); it takes a while but it does find a 20-move solution.

Comment: @HenryKeiter   
yes, it is. sorry about the naming not sounding great but i'm not english and i like to use sometimes terms of my own xD i was unable to still get some result. how does the final code looks with your alterations? but yes that's the correct solution. i guess that next the program tries to do trough depth-search and that is more problematic. i tried to use your little code help but i guess i'm not doing it well.

Comment: @RasecNoir Haha, I understand. I've updated my answer with the full text of my alterations (I left out the stuff I didn't change).

Comment: @HenryKeiter Thanks a lot. i tried it and it it's now on depth number 17 and working. 
I'll mark your answer as solution and I'll also try tomorrow one new idea i got to try to compare the nodes. Your help saved me some headaches. 
Thanks a lot for the help. ^_^